# Connection from google data studio to google cloud sql postgres with SSL

Tags: postgresql, ssl, google-cloud-sql, looker-studio

I've created one instance on Google Cloud with PostgreSql and I've connected the data studio with this database adding all the addresses specified in white list specified at link below

[https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7288010?hl=en]

With that solution I have to open access to my database to a lot of addresses. And this issue, associated to the fact that SSL is not supported is
a big lack of security.
Is there any different way to use google data studio for reports?
Maybe using CloudSqlProxy and considering google data studio as an external application from the GC environment?

Thanks for cooperation

Michele

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming you are concerned about data being exposed due to the lack of support for SSL. Though that is a valid concern in a lot of cases, for your specific use case, it should not matter:

- All the ip addresses that you have to whitelist [here](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7288010?hl=en]) are Google Server/infrastructure addresses.
- Data Studio as an application runs on Google's servers. So the communication between Google Cloud SQL and Google Data Studio will be entirely within Google's network. Even if it is not SSL, that traffic should not be exposed to outside world.
- The connection between any client computer (where report is being viewed) and Data Studio will always be HTTPS.

However, if you still want to have an SSL connection, you can create a [Community Connector](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector) in Apps Script that uses the [JDBC service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc) to connect to databases using SSL.

Comment: If security is not a concern, you can authorize 0.0.0.0/0 to permit any IP to connect. Saves you 10-15 minutes authorizing all those Google IPs.  https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/diagnose-issues

Comment: @MinhazKazi Regarding the 2nd point, this means that a hacker that creates a Google project and spins up an instance there, can try brute forcing into the database, without any firewall protection? Could you maybe be a bit more specific on what is "Google's network"?

Comment: I am not the expert in that area. You should be able to find the necessary information here: https://cloud.google.com/security/infrastructure/

Answer (score 0):

Try using client.key in both client fields.

The solution posted below helped here,
https://support.google.com/datastudio/thread/8739014?hl=en